# Does pictures in templates of components loads to clients browser at first load of angular app in bootstrapping period?

Tags: angular, lifecycle

actually, I want to know how an Angular 5 app loads and how many times it requests data from a server specifically when we move from one component to another component in one module.

Comment: You can check it out in `network` tab of any major browser.

Comment: I check and I found out that pictures load at first time a component loads and after that, the image doesn't load again, it looks like the image is somehow stored in local storage.

Answer (score -1):

The picture or component will load when the component load if you don't use lazy loading strategy or another strategy all photo or component in project will load because;the server will load all component in project.

if you use lazy loading strategy then the picture or component will call when the component load .

[LazyLoading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zXre.png)

[Lazy Loading Feature Modules](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules)